# If $f$ is continuous a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$, then it is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have seen the proofs of this just using the basic definition but I am trying to do this by using these functions:
$$\phi_f^{(n)}(x) := \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \chi_{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})},$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For a set $A$ we have $\chi_A$ defined as $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. If I can show that these functions are indeed measurable and that they converge to $f$ pointwise a.e., then $f$ is measurable. Clearly these sets are going to measurable, the set $\{\phi_f^{(n)}>a\}$ ends up being a union of intervals which of course is measurable for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$. My problem is showing that these things converge to $f$ pointwise. Here is my attempt, fix $x$ and consider $$|\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \chi_{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})}-f(x)| = |f(k^*/n)-f(x)|,$$ for some $k^* \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \in [\frac{k^*}{n},\frac{k^*+1}{n})$. I am just having trouble finding $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(k^*/n)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ when $n > N$.

Any help and tips?

Edit: I now see that as typing this that the $k^*$ does not work for every $n$. Rather for each $n$ there is $k_n$ such that $x \in [\frac{k_n}{n},\frac{k_n+1}{n}).$ Then the sequence $\{\frac{k_n}{n}\}$ converges to $x$. I think this proves the problem. I am not sure though. Also, I do not see where I use the fact that $f$ is continuous a.e. could someone help me see where this is used? Thanks again.

Comment: f(x) is assumed continuous almost everywhere? So choose just x in the set such that f(x) is continuous, then the desired inequality holds. In particular, it holds almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A:=\{x\, | f(x)\, \text{is continuous}\}$ and by assumption $\mu(A^c)=0$. Let $x\in A$ and then as you say, we can choose a sequence $k_n$ such that $\frac{k_n}{n}\rightarrow x$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x$, there must exist an $N$ such that $|f(\frac{k_n}{n})-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. Moreover, $x\in A$ was arbitrary, so this convergence happens pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: thank you for the help/confirmation!